# Current Address Operator ($) in MASM

Tags: assembly, operator-keyword, masm

I'm trying to write an ASM function (in MASM) that uses the current address operator ($) to pad code with NOPs in order to align code to 32-bytes.  My specific questions is, can I use an expression with the $ operator for condition code?

For example, my code looks like this:

```
needed equ ( $ mod 32 )
if needed eq 1
   db 090h
elseif needed eq 2
   db 66hh, 90h
.
.
.
else
  .err
endif
```

When I compile/build this code, I'm issued the following errors:

```
error A2026: constant expected
error A2052: forced error
```

The first of these errors refers to the following line:

```
if needed eq 1
```

Could you please let me know if the $ (current address operator) can be used this way in a conditional expression, and/or if there is another/better way to align code to 32-byte (or other byte) boundary?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Long time since I've uses MASM - but perhaps

```
ALIGN 32
```

may work.

or perhaps

```
db 090H dup (32 - ($ mode 32))
```

or
    db 090H dup ((32 - ($ mode 32)) mod 32)

Just tried this - but I use `TASM` so might need to be tickled...

```
NOPS EQU (4-(($-main)mod 4)) mod 4
if (NOPS NE 0)
    db NOPS mod 4 dup (90H)
endif
```

Not sure why you want 32-BYTE - 32-bit seems more appropriate (the above is for 32-BIT; use 32 in place of 4 for 32-byte)

In TASM (MASM-compatible mode)

```
    ALIGN DWORD
```

will align to a 4-byte boundary.

The problem with your approach is that `$` is relative to the code_segment. I'm assuming `MAIN` is the start of your program (or the first byte of the code segment, at least...)

`$-main` yields the offset from the start of the program segment and hence is simply a number, relative to nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I believe `ALIGN 32` is used for data-alignment and not code-alignment.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.  Could you please let me know what the `dup` instruction is, and how it would align the `db 090H` command to 32-bytes?  Thank you very much.